# Yii contact form not sending emails

Tags: forms, yii, contacts

Here's my controller action.

```
public function actionContact()
    {
        $model=new ContactForm;
        if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
        {   
            $model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];
            if($model->validate())
                {
                $headers="From: {$model->email}\r\nReply-To: {$model->email}";
                mail(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'],$model->subject,$model->body,$headers)`enter code here`;
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact','Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
                $this->refresh();
            }
        }
        $this->render('contact',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

It validates the data and shows up the success message. but email isn;t sent to the adminEmail address which is mine.

Thanks.

Comment: @Samuel Liew,and how will that help?

Comment: The mail() function may not return any error messages. Look in the web server logs to see if any errors are reported.

Answer (score 2):

If it is validating and showing flash messages, then it has to do with mail server, nothing to do with `yii`. I advise you look into mail server and see if it is running properly.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for it. Regarding the mail, I'm doing it on my localserver which is MAMP and in a live server http://esolution.ws/ here which is hosted on Hostgator. Also the mailing functionality working perfectly on some other part of this website. In fact It's working perfectly throughout the site except the contact page. You can give http://esolution.ws/index.php/site/contact it a try. I'll let you know if I receive anything.

Comment: Done, post me description of the email, let me see if u got anything

Comment: I'm not sure which description your'e asking.

Comment: Here's the controlelr action http://pastebin.com/HwvexebX The Model http://pastebin.com/3dVi78Hw The contact vie http://pastebin.com/D3YCdkAv

Comment: @aumio I asked description of the email I have sent from your link's contact page. Just to see if it is working.

Comment: @aumio You said `In fact It's working perfectly throughout the site except the contact page. You can give esolution.ws/index.php/site/contact it a try` So I tried sending message from contact page. Give me description part of the page so I see if it is working.

Comment: It's not working. I didn't get any email from the contact page.

Answer (score 2):

if you are doing in a localhost you must configure your mail server.you can use smtp for sending mails from localhost.If it is in mail server no need to configure.In yout config/main.php you can do like this for localhost

```html
 'mail' => array(
          'class' => 'application.extensions.yii-mail.YiiMail',
          'transportType' => 'php',
           'transportOptions'=>array(
           'host'=>'yourhostname',
           'port'=>'your port no'
            ),
          'viewPath' => 'application.views.mail',
          'logging' => true,
          'dryRun' => false
        ),
```

Note: i am using YiiMail Extension